# Do I need a javascript to convert an imported CSV field to a list in an Acrobat PDF?

Tags: javascript, csv, pdf, acrobat

I created a PDF using Acrobat.  It includes a List field to which I've mapped a CSV file.  The field is populated by an Solutions Business Manager (Micro Focus) form widget.  The field appears in comma-delimited form when the PDF is opened.  Do I need to apply a javascript in the Acrobat Prepare Form function, in the field Properties dialog box, in order to display the values as a List?  And where would I find such a script?

Comment: I can't imagine what "The field appears in comma-delimited form when the PDF is opened." means. Can you post the PDF somewhere so I can see what you mean?

Comment: For example: apple,orange,red apple,green apple, vegetables (all one line)

Comment: As a test, I got the java snippet event.value = "hello"; to work on the PDF by opening the PDF.  The snippet is in the PDF text field > Properties > Format > Custom Format script. 
However, when I create the PDF in the SBM UI, with an SBM transition, the script has no effect on the field value.  I tried downloading the PDF created by the SBM transition, and then closing and opening the PDF, but the script still didn't work.

Comment: A javascript worked on the SBM side:

Comment: var newListValue = commaDelimValue.replace(/,/g, '\n');

Comment: I may never find out if it's possible to edit the field on the PDF side.

Answer (score 0):

A javascript worked on the SBM side.  The relevant command is:

var newListValue = commaDelimValue.replace(/,/g, '\n');

I'm guessing that on account of whatever SBM process writes the content to the PDF, the usual javascript in the PDF Format tab won't work.